# Zend Framework 2: Getting an ordered SQL call

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

I've been trying to get an order ASC/DESC call for a field (let's say craeted), and I can't seem to figure out how to do it in ZF2.

Where am I going wrong..?

```
namespace Todo\Model;
class TodoTable extends AbstractTableGateway {
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Todo());

    $this->initialize();
}
public function fetchAll() {
    $resultSet = $this->select(array('user_id'=>$this->user_id));
return $resultSet;
}
}
```

Comment: Try the `order()` method -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.1.4/modules/zend.db.sql.html#order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a closure to manipulate the Select object like so:

```
public function fetchAll() 
{
    // The Select object will be passed to your Closure
    // before the query is executed.

    $resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) use () {
        //$select->columns(array('user_id', 'email', 'name')); 
        $select->order('name ASC'); 
    });

    return $resultSet;
}
```

An example passing through conditions / Where

```
public function fetchAll($someCondition) 
{
    // The Select object will be passed to your Closure
    // before the query is executed.

    $resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) use ($someCondition) {
        $select->columns(array('user_id', 'email', 'name')); 
        $select->order('name ASC'); 
        $select->where(array('user_id'=> $someCondition));
    });

    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: $user_id = $this->user_id;
$resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) use ($user_id) {
        $select->order('created DESC'); 
        $select->where(array('user_id' => $user_id));
    });